# Hashtable Visualizer in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, dom, hash-map

Implementation is based on the MVC design pattern, with callbacks to allow model and view to communicate with controller.

Concerns:

It's not ideal to have async code inside the model, i.e the model should be as close to a basic
hashtable implementation as possible. However since we need to set a chain of calls to the view
to animate things while in the middle of the model methods, I couldn't see another way.

In the middle of animations the user trying to insert new keys would cause problems,
so I temporarily disable the ability to click on the buttons. This works well from the clients
point of view, but in terms of code I'm wondering if there's a cleaner way to do it.

hashtable.ts

```
const enum ModelMessages {
  Searching,
  Found,
  UpdateVal,
  ExpandArray,
  NotFound,
}

// implementation of a hashtable with linear probing
class HashTable {
  private readonly notifyController: (message: ModelMessages, arg: any) => void;
  private readonly LOAD_FACTOR: number;
  private keys: (number | null)[];
  private entryCount: number;
  private arrayLength: number;

  constructor(
    initialCapacity: number,
    notify: (message: ModelMessages, arg: any) => void
  ) {
    this.notifyController = notify;
    this.LOAD_FACTOR = 0.75;
    this.keys = [];
    this.entryCount = 0;
    this.arrayLength = initialCapacity;
  }

  public async add(key: number): Promise<void> {
    let index;
    let offset = 0;

    do {
      index = this.hashFunction(key + offset);
      offset++;
      await this.notifyController(ModelMessages.Searching, index);
    } while (this.keys[index] !== undefined && this.keys[index] !== key);

    await this.notifyController(ModelMessages.Found, index);
    await this.notifyController(ModelMessages.UpdateVal, [index, key]);

    this.entryCount += this.keys[index] === undefined ? 1 : 0;
    this.keys[index] = key;
    this.handleArrayResize();
  }

  public async contains(key: number): Promise<boolean> {
    return (await this.getIndexOfKey(key)) !== -1;
  }

  public clear(): void {
    this.keys = [];
    this.entryCount = 0;
  }

  public async delete(key: number): Promise<boolean> {
    const index = await this.getIndexOfKey(key);

    if (index === -1) {
      return false;
    }

    this.keys[index] = null;

    await this.notifyController(ModelMessages.UpdateVal, [index, null]);

    return true;
  }

  private handleArrayResize(): void {
    if (this.arrayLength * this.LOAD_FACTOR < this.entryCount) {
      this.expandArray();
    }
  }

  private hashFunction(arg: number): number {
    return Math.abs(arg) % this.arrayLength;
  }

  private async expandArray(): Promise<void> {
    const oldKeyArray = this.keys;

    this.clear();
    this.arrayLength *= 2;
    await this.notifyController(ModelMessages.ExpandArray, this.arrayLength);

    for (let i = 0; i < this.arrayLength / 2; i++) {
      if (oldKeyArray[i] !== undefined && oldKeyArray[i] !== null) {
        await this.add(<number>oldKeyArray[i]);
      }
    }
  }

  private async getIndexOfKey(key: number): Promise<number> {
    let index;
    let offset = 0;

    do {
      index = this.hashFunction(key + offset);
      await this.notifyController(ModelMessages.Searching, index);

      if (this.keys[index] === undefined) {
        await this.notifyController(ModelMessages.NotFound, index);
        return -1;
      }

      offset++;
    } while (this.keys[index] !== key);

    await this.notifyController(ModelMessages.Found, index);

    return index;
  }
}
```

controller.ts

```
const hashtable = new HashTable(8, readMessageFromModel);
const view = new View(8, readMessageFromView);

async function readMessageFromView(
  message: ViewMessages,
  arg: any
): Promise<void> {
  switch (message) {
    case ViewMessages.Search:
      await hashtable.contains(<number>arg);
      break;
    case ViewMessages.Insert:
      await hashtable.add(<number>arg);
      break;
    case ViewMessages.Delete:
      await hashtable.delete(<number>arg);
      break;
    case ViewMessages.Clear:
      hashtable.clear();
      view.resetArray();
      break;
    default:
      throw "View has notified controller with unsupported type";
  }
}

async function readMessageFromModel(
  message: ModelMessages,
  arg: any
): Promise<void> {
  switch (message) {
    case ModelMessages.Searching:
      await view.highlightSearching(<number>arg);
      break;
    case ModelMessages.Found:
      await view.highlightFound(<number>arg);
      break;
    case ModelMessages.NotFound:
      await view.highlightNotFound(<number>arg);
      break;
    case ModelMessages.UpdateVal:
      view.updateCellValueAt.apply(view, <[number, number | null]>arg);
      break;
    case ModelMessages.ExpandArray:
      view.expandArray(<number>arg);
      break;
    default:
      throw "Model has notified controller with unsupported type";
  }
}
```

view.ts

````
const enum ViewMessages {
  Insert,
  Search,
  Delete,
  Clear,
}

class View {
  private arrayLength: number;
  private readonly notifyController: (message: ViewMessages, arg: any) => void;
  private readonly ARRAY_WIDTH: number = 1500;

  constructor(
    defaultLength: number,
    notify: (message: ViewMessages, arg: any) => void
  ) {
    this.arrayLength = defaultLength;
    this.notifyController = notify;
    this.initialiseView();
  }

  public async highlightFound(index: number): Promise<void> {
    await this.highlightGeneric(index, "#32CD32");
  }

  public async highlightSearching(index: number): Promise<void> {
    await this.highlightGeneric(index, "#33D5FF");
  }

  public async highlightNotFound(index: number): Promise<void> {
    await this.highlightGeneric(index, "red");
  }

  public updateCellValueAt(index: number, val: number | null): void {
    if (val !== null) {
      this.getCellInDOM(index).innerHTML = `${val}`;
    } else {
      this.getCellInDOM(index).innerHTML = "⚰️";
    }
  }

  public expandArray(newSize: number): void {
    this.arrayLength = newSize;
    this.resetArray();
  }

  public resetArray(): void {
    this.clearArray();
    this.createArrayInDOM();
  }

  private async highlightGeneric(index: number, color: string): Promise<void> {
    this.getCellInDOM(index).style.backgroundColor = color;

    await this.delay();

    this.getCellInDOM(index).style.backgroundColor = "white";
  }

  private clearArray(): void {
    const array = this.getArrayinDOM(document.querySelector("#array"));

    array.innerHTML = "";
  }

  private initialiseView(): void {
    this.createArrayInDOM();
    this.addMenuClickListeners();
  }

  private addMenuClickListeners(): void {
    document
      .querySelector("#search")
      ?.addEventListener("click", () => this.searchForKey());
    document
      .querySelector("#insert")
      ?.addEventListener("click", () => this.insertKey());
    document
      .querySelector("#delete")
      ?.addEventListener("click", () => this.deleteKey());
    document
      .querySelector("#clear")
      ?.addEventListener("click", () => this.clear());
  }

  private clear(): void {
    this.notifyController(ViewMessages.Clear, null);
  }

  private async notifyControllerWithInputValue(
    inputField: HTMLInputElement | null,
    message: ViewMessages
  ): Promise<void> {
    this.blockMenuButtons();

    if (inputField !== null) {
      const input = <HTMLInputElement>inputField;

      if (!isNaN(parseInt(input.value))) {
        await this.notifyController(message, parseInt(input.value));
      }
    } else {
      throw "Input field argument was null";
    }

    this.enableMenuButtons();
  }

  private searchForKey(): void {
    this.notifyControllerWithInputValue(
      document.querySelector("#search-input"),
      ViewMessages.Search
    );
  }

  private insertKey(): void {
    this.notifyControllerWithInputValue(
      document.querySelector("#insert-input"),
      ViewMessages.Insert
    );
  }

  private deleteKey(): void {
    this.notifyControllerWithInputValue(
      document.querySelector("#delete-input"),
      ViewMessages.Delete
    );
  }

  private blockMenuButtons(): void {
    this.getButtonInDOM(document.querySelector("#search")).style.pointerEvents =
      "none";
    this.getButtonInDOM(document.querySelector("#insert")).style.pointerEvents =
      "none";
    this.getButtonInDOM(document.querySelector("#delete")).style.pointerEvents =
      "none";
    this.getButtonInDOM(document.querySelector("#clear")).style.pointerEvents =
      "none";
  }

  private enableMenuButtons(): void {
    this.getButtonInDOM(document.querySelector("#search")).style.pointerEvents =
      "auto";
    this.getButtonInDOM(document.querySelector("#insert")).style.pointerEvents =
      "auto";
    this.getButtonInDOM(document.querySelector("#delete")).style.pointerEvents =
      "auto";
    this.getButtonInDOM(document.querySelector("#clear")).style.pointerEvents =
      "auto";
  }

  private getButtonInDOM(button: HTMLButtonElement | null): HTMLButtonElement {
    if (button === null) {
      throw "Button supplied is null";
    } else {
      return <HTMLButtonElement>button;
    }
  }

  private createArrayInDOM(): void {
    const array = this.getArrayinDOM(document.querySelector("#array"));
    const row = document.createElement("tr");

    array.style.width = `${this.ARRAY_WIDTH}px`;
    array.append(row);

    for (let i = 0; i < this.arrayLength; i++) {
      row.append(this.createCellInDOM(i));
    }
  }

  private createCellInDOM(index: number): HTMLTableCellElement {
    const newCell = document.createElement("td");

    newCell.style.width = `${this.ARRAY_WIDTH / this.arrayLength}px`;
    newCell.style.height = `${this.ARRAY_WIDTH / this.arrayLength}px`;
    newCell.style.fontSize = `${(this.ARRAY_WIDTH / this.arrayLength) * 4}%`;
    newCell.className = "cell";

    return newCell;
  }

  private getCellInDOM(index: number): HTMLTableCellElement {
    const arrayDOM = this.getArrayinDOM(document.querySelector("#array"));
    const rowDOM = arrayDOM.rows[0];
    const cellDOM = rowDOM.cells[index];

    return cellDOM;
  }

  private getArrayinDOM(array: HTMLTableElement | null): HTMLTableElement {
    if (array === null) {
      throw "Element supplied is null";
    } else {
      return <HTMLTableElement>array;
    }
  }

  private delay(): Promise<string> {
    const delayTimeInMilliseconds = 300;

    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      setTimeout(resolve, delayTimeInMilliseconds);
    });
  }
}
```
````